# VS Code does not display output when debugging C program

Tags: c, gcc, gdb

I've written a simple C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char first[20];
    char last[20];
    printf("Enter first name: ");
    scanf("%s", first);
    printf("Enter last name: ");
    scanf("%s", last);
    printf("Hello %c %c. \n", first, last);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I built the program with compiler from GCC using `gcc.exe build active file` command and debugged it with the GDB configuration. There is no output in the debug console unless I set `'externalConsole' = true` in `launch.json`, however if I do so I will not be able to examine if my program works or not, because the console window closes immediately after I have entered the strings.

How should I solve this problem and make sure I can debug the program properly?

Comment: try rebuilding with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror`; probably want a revised format `"Hello %s %s\n"`; also consider the case when > 20 bytes are entered

Comment: GDB can also debug the code in steps using: `b main` followed by `run` and then `step` command. Use `gcc -g [filename].c` to compile.

Comment: @Milag @sourabh-choure I need to make a correction: I was compiling using the `C/C++: gcc.exe build active file` command.